# Extract from string using regular expression

Tags: regex, r

I have a string:

```
s <- "test.test AS field1, ablh.blah AS field2, faslk.lsdf AS field3"
```

I want to convert to:

```
"field1, field2, field3"
```

I know that the regular expression `(\w+)(?:,|$)` will extract the strings I want ('field1,' etc) but I can't figure out how to extract it with `gsub`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
## Preparation
s <- "test.test AS field1, ablh.blah AS field2, faslk.lsdf AS field3"
pat <- "(\\w+)(?:,|$)"  ## Note the doubly-escaped \\w

## Use the powerful gregexpr/regmatches one-two punch
m <- gregexpr(pat, s)
paste(regmatches(s, m)[[1]], collapse=" ")
# [1] "field1, field2, field3"
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was trying to do and just couldn't quite get it to work.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

With `strapplyc` in the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) one can do it with a particularly simple regular expression which extracts each string of word characters that follows `" AS "` (If the field can contain non-word characters then replace `\\w` with the appropriate expression, for example any char that is not a space or comma: `[^ ,]`):

```
> library(gsubfn)
> strapplyc(s, " AS (\\w+)", simplify = toString)[[1]]
[1] "field1, field2, field3"
```